# Only in Live - Wildcard Custom Redirects not working (BVN 404 handler)

Tags: episerver, episerver-7, episerver-8

I'm using the BVN 404 handler nuget package to do redirects in my episerver website.

I have a developer, staging and live enviroment.

One of the redirect rules I have is a wild card one. (Box checked)

so for example:

```
OLD URL: /uk/products/
```

Should go to the

```
NEW URL: /uk/services/
```

as I have the wild card box ticked

`/uk/products/productname` - Should also be redirected.

This is working in my developer and staging enviroments, but the WILD CARD is not working on our live website.

So on live you only get redirected if the URL is the exact match... So

```
/uk/products/
```

that will work and you are redirected. but it only half works in live becuase

```
/uk/products/productName
```

is not working in live but is working locally and in our staging enviroment.

I can't work out why, I have checked on the live server to make sure there are no other IIS re-write rules that may be conflicting, I have also made sure we have the same rules in both enviroments, but it still is not working.

Does anyone have any ideas about what could cuase this?

What other things can I check on live?

Any ideas?

Comment: Hey Ayo, are you being redirected at all when hitting '/uk/products/productname'? I've had issues previously when another redirect in the BVN handler was conflicting with another redirect and therefore causing wildcards to not work properly.

Comment: Maybe the route `/uk/products/productName ` already exists in the live environment for another page. If that's the case then the redirect function won't work as it only works when the default routing return a 404 message